# QRCode in Crystal Report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, sapb1

I want to add a QRCode in A/R Invoice that hen scanned displays the results as in the field of "Create QRCode From" in SAP B1
Whenever I add the command and create the links, the design view loses its field in Crystal Report and I can not design the crystal Report Invoice
POV: This is for Version 10 Of SAP B1

Below is the detailed steps I took to create the "FileContnt" to display the QR

[image: This is the URL I had put which is to be displayed once I scan the QR]

[image: This is the Crystal design before adding the QR code]

[image: This is the code I input in the Database Expert as a Command]

[image: I linked the DocEntry to ObjAbs and set it as left outer join and also linked ObjType with Objtype command]

[image: Once saved, this is the error now, all the fields disappear and I can't design the report]

Thanks